# Creating a test UI for testers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, architecture, tdd

I have a set of methods contained within their own project which are being used within a rather large (monolithic) application.  Because of this testers have been complaining that there is no simple way to test them.

Therefore I proposed creating a simple app which will use reflection on an assembly and allow the testers to input their own parameters into each individual method (and check the result).  I **do** have a full suite of unit tests but think it'd be best to give the methods a presence for the testers.

- Does this sound like a good idea?
- Is there anything already out there that I could use?

Or perhaps I'm missing something completely obvious.

Comment: Nope, the tester in my team would definitely NOT accept this.

Comment: Is there a reason the suite of unit tests is not enough?

Comment: @Metthieu - The problem is the testers need to ensure the big picture works, but it's a real challenge due to the way the current software works.  There are too many variables to be able to nail down what's being tested, so I was trying to provide access **only** to the changes.

Comment: It sounds sort of like http://fitnesse.org (however I've never used it so I could be wrong). I'm not sure you should be exposing methods but features.

Answer (score 6):

> I have a set of methods contained within their own project which are
>   being used within a rather large (monolithic) application. Because of
>   this testers have been complaining that there is no simple way to test
>   them.

The only way to test *methods* is through unit tests, which you say there's already a full suite of.

If that project is purely internal (and it seems to be the case since you had to use reflection to expose it), testers shouldn't even know about it.

Testing the internal guts of an architecture is not a tester's job, it's a developer's job.

Comment: Totally agree: why would a tester test a code library? That's what unit tests are for.

Comment: The problem is the application is massive and poorly written.  Ideally we'd refactor this, but since we don't have time right now I've made my changes in a separate project.  Testers need to ensure what I've done works in the big picture, but how can I provide them access to this?

Comment: If they wan't to test the big picture, after Your changes, then in my opinion full regression test suite is needed to be performed. Testing methods separately is not the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

The method You proposed is obviously a solution to Your problem. In previous comments, there have been many (mine also) questions about the reason You want to do it. But since You are sure because of certain reasons (we know the corporate world, right?)  that the testers should manually test each method from the library and the unit tests You already got are not enough, then what You proposed should work fine in my opinion.

The problem You got seems to be lack of trust to unit testing / wrong approach of someone who made the decision that testers should check the library.